# How to find a place where to insert value into ordered array using binary search?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am doing programming project from book about data structures and algorithms and I need to implement insertion into ordered array using binary search.

My initial implementation for this using linear approach is:

```
public void insert(long value) {      // put element into array
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)      // find where it goes
        if (a[j] > value)             // (linear search)
            break;
    for (int k = nElems; k > j; k--)  // move bigger ones up
        a[k] = a[k-1];
    a[j] = value;                     // insert it
    nElems++;                         // increment size
}  // end insert()
```

But, I am stuck when I tried to create something similar using binary search approach.
Here is what I did:

```
public void insert(long value) {
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = nElems-1;
    int curIn;

    while(lowerBound < upperBound) {

        curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

        if(arr[curIn]>value && arr[curIn-1] < value) {
            for(int k=nElems; k>curIn; k--) 
                arr[k] = arr[k-1];
            arr[curIn] = value;
        } else {
            if(arr[curIn] > value)
                upperBound = curIn-1;
            else
                lowerBound = curIn+1;
        }
    }   
}  // end insert()
```

I think my main mistake is the following :

- I don't have any logic which handles empty array case.

Give me some advice please. I just started to learn this stuff about a week ago, so some explanation would be great.

Thank you in advance, Nick.

Comment: What does not work?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have an empty array at the result. It should be filled by my values, but it doesn't

Comment: where do you initialize `nElems`?

Comment: Since you have to shift all the elements after the one inserted anyway, using binary search does not seem to have much benefit here. Sure, you have O(logn) instead of O(n) for searchling, but you still need O(n) for shifting the other elements, so overall complexity stays at O(n).

Comment: Useful series of articles on binary search on Dr Dobbs http://www.drdobbs.com/author/Andrew-Koenig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the loop you can keep a loop invariant(insert position always in interval `[lowerBound upperBound]`).

So when `arr[curIn] > value`, halve the interval to `[lowerBound curIn]`

when `arr[curIn] <= value`, halve the interval to `[curIn+1 upperBound]`

After the loop, lowerBound is the position to insert.

```
//Assume arr, nElems are declared somewhere else and enough space to insert...
public void insert(long value) {
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = nElems;
    int curIn;
    while(lowerBound < upperBound) {
        curIn = (lowerBound+upperBpund)/2;
        if(arr[curIn] > value) {
            upperBound = curIn;
        } else {
            lowerBound = curIn+1;
        }
    }
    //note lowerBound may equal nElems, it works anyway
    for(int k = nElems; k > lowerBound; k--) {
        arr[k] = arr[k-1];
    }
    arr[lowerBound] = value;
    nElems++;
}
```

Comment: Two adjustment is required. 1. update nElems after insert 2. initiate upperBound with `nElems`, not `nElems-1`